# Immediately kill a running future thread

Tags: clojure, future, cancellation

I'm using

```
(def f 
   (future 
      (while (not (Thread/interrupted)) 
         (function-to-run))))

(Thread/sleep 100)
(future-cancel f)
```

to cancel my code after a specified amount of time (100ms).
The problem is, I need to cancel the already running function 'function-to-run' as well, it is important that it really stops executing that function after 100ms.
Can I somehow propagate the interrupted signal to the function?
The function is not third-party, I wrote it myself.

Comment: I totally revised my answer, may want to see if it applies for your use case.

Comment: It seems for me running an agent instead of a future would be much better for your usecase. I.e. you could control over an atom if the next iteration of your agent should be issued: `(if @running (send *agent* nil))` (therefore you don't even need the `while` loop). You could check the state of the atom as often as you want inside your running function and return prematurely if necessary. (See Rich Hickey's famous ants.clj for an example.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The basic thing to note here is: you cannot safely kill a thread without its own cooperation.  Since you are the owner of the function you wish to be able to kill prematurely, it makes sense to allow the function to cooperate and die gracefully and safely.

```
(defn function-to-run
  []
  (while work-not-done
    (if-not (Thread/interrupted)
      ; ... do your work
      (throw (InterruptedException. "Function interrupted...")))))

(def t (Thread. (fn []
                  (try
                    (while true
                      (function-to-run))
                    (catch InterruptedException e
                      (println (.getMessage e)))))))
```

To begin the thread

```
(.start t)
```

To interrupt it:

```
(.interrupt t)
```

Your approach was not sufficient for your use case because the `while` condition was checked only after control flow returned from `function-to-run`, but you wanted to stop `function-to-run` during its execution.  The approach here is only different in that the condition is checked more frequently, namely, every time through the loop in `function-to-run`.  Note that instead of throwing an exception from `function-to-run`, you could also return some value indicating an error, and as long as your loop in the main thread checks for this value, you don't have to involve exceptions at all.

If your `function-to-run` doesn't feature a loop where you can perform the `interrupted` check, then it likely is performing some blocking I/O.  You may not be able to interrupt this, though many APIs will allow you to specify a timeout on the operation.  In the worst case, you can still perform intermittent checks for `interrupted` in the function around your calls.  But the bottom line still applies: you cannot safely forcibly stop execution of code running in the function; it should yield control cooperatively.

Note:
My original answer here involved presenting an example in which java's `Thread.stop()` was used (though strongly discouraged).  Based on feedback in the comments, I revised the answer to the one above.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I want. It is terminating much earlier, but still not immediately, it seems. Is immediate killing not possible? Anyways, it is much better than before.

Comment: `Thread/stop` is annotated with giant Biohazard/Radioactive/Death signs in the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#stop()). It's not just difficult to use safely, it is *impossible* to use safely, and you should never use it. The deprecation notice comes with a description of what you should do instead, and indeed is the perfect solution to the question being asked here.

Comment: You should not use Thread.stop(). It is possible to instead use Thread.interrupt(). You can catch and handle the InterruptedException in the function. If you are actually blocking on an I/O operation, this may or may not work (read the operation docs) and you should consider other options.

Comment: @AlexMiller Updated answer; knew I shouldn't have even mentioned such an approach, as I'd never use it myself. Thanks for the feedback

Comment: @amalloy Updated answer; knew I shouldn't have even mentioned such an approach, as I'd never use it myself. Thanks for the feedback

Comment: Most (all?) blocking IO will respond to Thread/interrupt calls quite quickly, rather than waiting for the ordinary timeout to expire.